# WordPress Multisite With and Without WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website with multisite with two themes. Let support

1. example.com ( Main Domain - Theme not compatible with WooCommerce )
2. example.com/store ( Theme compatible with WooCommerce )

My question is can I display My WooCommerce Product in my Main Domain ?

I want to display a product from example.com/store and display it in a Page of my main domain.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You would need to write a custom WP Query.

WordPress allows you to pull post type data from your other sites within your multisite network, you will need to grab the ID of the individual site you want to query. This is found within your Multisite Admin Dashboard.

This is a close duplicate of [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74326), the answer and code examples you want can be found there.

Thanks.